# How can I disable unnecessary escaping in XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

XStream by default unnecessarily escapes `>`,`"`     ... etc.

Is there a way to disable this (and only escape `<`, `&`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the result of the default PrettyPrintWriter. Personally, I like to escape both < and >. It makes the output look more balanced.

If you want canonicalized XML output, you should use the C14N API provided in Java.

If the streamed content includes XML, CDATA is a better option. Here is how I did it,

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(
           new DomDriver() {
               public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer out) {
                   return new MyWriter(out);}});
String xml = xstream.toXML(myObj);

    ......

public class MyWriter extends PrettyPrintWriter {
    public MyWriter(Writer writer) {
        super(writer);
    }

    protected void writeText(QuickWriter writer, String text) { 
        if (text.indexOf('<') < 0) {
            writer.write(text);
        }
        else { 
            writer.write("<[CDATA["); writer.write(text); writer.write("]]>"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A CDATA section is not an complete alternative to escaping, as the sequence `]]>` can't go in it. (It's sometimes escaped into two CDATA sections.)

Comment: Note that this behaviour switches off escaping globally for your XStream object. If you only want to disable escaping when the text contains '<' or other specific characters, you can replace  `writer.write(text);` with `super.write(writer, text);`, thereby restoring the default escaping behaviour for all other cases.

Comment: The code that constructs the CDATA section should also contain an exclamation mark, as in `writer.write("<![CDATA[");`

Answer (score 1):

Cdata does not worked for me,
Finally i have to work with Apache StringUtils.

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(xml, new String[]{"&lt;","&quot;","&apos;","&gt;"}, new String[]{"<","\"","'",">"});
```

Answer (score 0):

XStream doesn't write XML on its own, it uses various libs ("drivers"?) to do so.

Just choose one which doesn't. The list is on their site. I guess it would use XOM by default.