# How to avoid Xstream to produce xml file with &amp or &quote or similar chars?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I start to work with `Xstream` with Java.
I have a list of cars named `CarList`.
I have a car as an object named `Car`.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.alias("Car", Car.class);
xstream.alias("Cars", CarList.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(CarList.class, "list");
xstream.toXML(list, new FileWriter(fileName+xmlExtension));
```

Unfortunately each time I save my file. My XML contains `&quot` and `&amp` instead of `"` and `&`.
What am I doing wrong? Should I use a regex for replacing those characters or there is something better to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem quite intersting, so I made a little investigation about it.

XStream doesn't write XML on its own, it uses various libs ("drivers"?) to do so. Therefore, the reason could be found in concrete implemenation of using `HierarchicalStreamDriver`.

First of all, I have tried to debug with `XStream xstream = new XStream()`. In this case you can see a `switch` operatior to write these replacements (see `PrettyPrintWriter.writeText()`):

```
private void writeText(String text) {
    int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case '\0':
                this.writer.write(NULL);
                break;
            case '&':
                this.writer.write(AMP);
                break;
            case '<':
                this.writer.write(LT);
                break;
            case '>':
                this.writer.write(GT);
                break;
            case '"':
                this.writer.write(QUOT);
                break;
            case '\'':
                this.writer.write(APOS);
                break;
            case '\r':
                this.writer.write(SLASH_R);
                break;
            default:
                this.writer.write(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Second, I have tried that with your example with `XStream xstream = new XStream(driver)`. The final debug point with available sources (I did not go deeper) is `StaxWriter.setValue()`. It means, that reason is not in `XStream` itself, but in the `XMLStreamWriter` that is used to write a xml file. I have found [XMLStreamWriter writeCharacters without escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783758/xmlstreamwriter-writecharacters-without-escaping)
. I have tried one given solution: `streamWriterFactory.setProperty("escapeCharacters", false);` and my current solution is:

```
StaxDriver driver = new StaxDriver();
driver.getOutputFactory().setProperty("escapeCharacters", false);
XStream xstream = new XStream(driver);
```

I have fixed the problem of replacing `"` and `&`. But problem is that if you have e.g. `<>` in one of your strings - they **will not** be changed as well, and it breaks the final xml.

So, I do not know your context, probably this light solution could be enough for you. If not and you have `<>` symbols you your output, then I would find a place where driver reads **escapeCharacters** property and find out how to disable only specific set of escape characters.

I do not know is there any standard way or not, sorry. But it seems that all results I have found are not universal and to solve this correct, we have to know a task context. One of not bad solution, as you mentioned, is just replace required escape symbols in final xml: [XStream apostrophe Issue in converting Java Object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231954/xstream-apostrophe-issue-in-converting-java-object-to-xml) and [How can I disable unnecessary escaping in XStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891305/how-can-i-disable-unnecessary-escaping-in-xstream)
.

Comment: I understand better after reading your lines, the way you replied and the pedagogy behind. It was very confusing for me to understand what was going on. Thank you