# Jaxb2Marshaller problem with String that contains '&'

Tags: java, jaxb, spring-batch

I'm using the `Jaxb2Marshaller` from `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller` in my Spring Batch application to marshall XML with annotated classes. The implementation of the `Marshaller` is:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller productMarshaller() {
        
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler", new XmlCharacterEscapeHandler());
        
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[] {Product.class, TechSpecs.class});
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
    return marshaller;
}
```

The `Marshaller` is used inside a `StaxEventItemWriter` that is implemented as following:

```
@Bean(name = "writer")
@StepScope
public StaxEventItemWriter<Product> writer (
        @Value("#{jobParameters['path']}") String path,
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['currentFile']}") String fileName
    ) {
        
    Map<String, String> rootElementAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    rootElementAttributes.put("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(path + fileName);
        
    return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Product>()
            .name("writer")
            .version("1.0")
            .encoding("UTF-8")
            .standalone(false)
            .rootTagName("Products")
            .rootElementAttributes(rootElementAttributes)
            .headerCallback(headerCallback(null, null))
            .footerCallback(footerCallback())
            .marshaller(productMarshaller())
            .resource(file)
            .build();
}
```

Now the problem is that when I run the code, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I found out that the exception is thrown because my `Product` object has a String attribute that may contain a `&`. The `&` is not allowed in XML and has to be escaped.

Why is the `Jaxb2Marshaller` not auto escaping the `&` character? As far as I understand the `Marshaller` should take care of escaping characters.

I tried to escape the character my self in the item processor with the `StringEscapeUtils`, e.g. `product.setFullName(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(dbExport.getFullName()));`, but this didn't help. Also the String will be changed from `&` to `&amp;`, which also contains a `&`.

I also tried to use my own implementation of a `CharacterEscapeHandler`, but the `marshaller.setMarshallerProperties()` does not have any visible effect on the `Marshaller`. Do I have to set the properties for the Marshaller differently?

```
public class XmlCharacterEscapeHandler implements CharacterEscapeHandler {

    @Override
    public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal, Writer out) throws IOException { 
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();   
        for(int i = start; i < start + length; i++) {
            buffer.write(ch[i]);
        }
        String escapedString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(buffer.toString());
        out.write(escapedString);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately I could not resolve my issue until now. Therefore, I switched from `Jaxb2Marshaller` to `XStreamMarshaller`. Here I get a similar issue. As far as I can tell the underlying `XStream` should use a `PrettyPrintWriter` that will auto convert `&` to `&amp;` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141964/4191735 This is not happening. For me there is always an problem with `&`. Why does the escaping not work? Also escaping the String itself and force converting it to UTF-8 does not help.

**Minimal Complete Example**
Main:

```
package com.mwe;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.mwe")
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args)));
    }
}
```

BatchConfig:

```
package com.mwe;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.builder.StaxEventItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Product> reader() {
            
        FlatFileItemReader<Product> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Product>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("test.csv"));

        DefaultLineMapper<Product> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CustomFieldMapper());

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"ID", "NAME"});
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);

        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Product, Xml> processor() {
        return new Processor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Xml> writer () {
        
        return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Xml>()
                .name("writer")
                .version("1.0")
                .encoding("UTF-8")
                .standalone(false)
                .rootTagName("products")
                .marshaller(getMarshaller())
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("test.xml"))
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return (stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Product, Xml>chunk(2)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public XStreamMarshaller getMarshaller() {
        
        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

CustomFieldMapper

```
package com.mwe;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;


public class CustomFieldMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Product> {

    public Product mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs) {
        
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(fs.readString("ID"));
        product.setName(fs.readString("NAME"));
        
        return product;
    }
    
}
```

ItemProcessor:

```
package com.mwe;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Product, Xml> {
    
    @Override
    public Xml process(final Product product) {
        
        Xml xml = new Xml();
        xml.setId(Integer.parseInt(product.getId()));
        xml.setName(product.getName());
        
        return xml;
    }

}
```

Product:

```
package com.mwe;

public class Product {
    
    private String id;
    
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

Xml:

```
package com.mwe;

public class Xml {

    private int id;
    
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

Application Properties:

```
# Spring config
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.batch.initialize-schema=never

# Logging data source
spring.datasource.logging.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.logging.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.logging.hikar.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.logging.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.logging.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.logging.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.datasource.logging.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/logging?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mwe</groupId>
    <artifactId>mwe</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>mwe</name>
    <description>Minimal working example</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

test.csv:

```
"ID"|"NAME"
1|"Product 1"
2|"Product 1 & Addition"
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error. If you provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, I can take a look.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I added the minimal example.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3745.

This issue will be fixed in v4.3.2/v4.2.6 which are planned to be released on March 18, 2021. Please check the [milestone page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/milestone/120) on GitHub in case the release date changes.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Are there any workarounds or is it better to remove the characters that have to be escaped from my data until the release on March 18th? So I can continue with the development and then update later on.

Comment: The issue actually happens only when the `StaxEventItemWriter` is set to be transactional (which is `true` by default). Based on your minimal example, you are transforming a csv file to an xml file, which does not require the writer to be transactional. I added `.transactional(false)` on your item writer and the exception did not happen. Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes setting `transactional(false)` resolves the issue for the given example. In my main application I'm using a `JdbcItemReader` so I will wait for the release.

Comment: `JdbcCursorItemReader` will not participate in any transactions created as part of the step processing (see its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html)). So it should be fine to disable that flag on the writer without impacting the reader.

Comment: That said, are you willing to help testing the fix for this issue since you have a project ready for that? We have a PR with a fix here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/3843. All you need is apply the patch on the 4.3.x branch, build and test against the snapshot version. That would be a great contribution!

Comment: Sure, do I have to report my result anywhere?

Comment: Oh great thank you! Yes, you can add a comment on that PR.